# Thymeleaf using arrow keys

Tags: thymeleaf

I was searching for implement the possibility to navigate through dynamic lists in Thymeleafe using arrow keys. I was expecting an build-in solution but I haven`t found any in the documentation. Therefore here my simple question, is there no other possibility to ask which key was pressed and depending on it use Java Script to change the focus?

Thanks, Matthias

Comment: Thymeleaf performs server-side rendering of the page. The events, you mention, happen after the page already rendered. Those events should be handled by client-side JS.

Comment: I assume the "dynamic lists" part of the question means that the JS won't know in advance what exactly it has to navigate through. Slava is right, of course - Thymeleaf itself cannot directly/actively help you. But your Thymeleaf template can include, for example, customized class names for the relevant tags in your list. This would allow the JS to select the right elements, at least. If this is not the point, then perhaps you can add an example to your question, to clarify things.